# Why is a typeclass constraint added when I did not define it in my original type definition?

Tags: haskell

In prelude I am checking some types.

```
*> let kessel :: (Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a; kessel = undefined
*> :t kessel 1 2
kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a
```

I don't get why `Num a` is included as a typeclass constraint on the type of `kessel 1 2`. It wasn't in the original type definition of kessel. Why does it appear in `:t kessel 1 2`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the result of unification of the type of the expression `1` with the type of `kessel`.  Note that the type of the expression `1` is:

```
> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
```

When this type variable `p` is unified with the type variable `a` in:

```
kessel :: (Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a
```

the result is that `a` has both `Ord` and `Num` constraints.  In particular:

```
> :t kessel 1
kessel 1 :: (Ord a, Num b, Num a) => b -> a
>
```

When you provide the extra argument satisfying `Num b => b`, you get the final type:

```
> :t kessel 1 2
kessel 1 2 :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
>
```

The `Num b` constraint has been discharged by supplying `2`, and neither it nor any other reference to the type `b` appear in the final signature.

Also, note that if this `Num a` constraint *didn't* appear in the final type, then it would be type-correct to write:

```
> kessel 1 2 :: Bool
```

since `Bool` is clearly of type `Ord a => a`, with the implication that the type of `1` has somehow been unified with `Bool`.